# How to deserialize this JSON array

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

The JSON is coming in like this (pseudo code):

```
[{one-off intro object}, [{object},{object},{object}]]
```

So it's an array where the first thing in the array is an object I'm not interested in and the second is another array full of the objects I actually want to deserialize.

How can I do this with JSON.NET?

Comment: Please read [ask], provide a [mcve] (emphasis on **verifiable**, as what you show obviously isn't valid JSON) and share what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any specific problems?

Comment: Well first off you should [see if it's even valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) (hint, it isn't)

Comment: I don't have any control over the format of the JSON.

Comment: Either it's valid JSON, or it's not. In this case, it's not, so you can't use a JSON tool.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not calling it invalid because of the spoofed data, right? It's the actual structure that is invalid? (Array with one object and another array)

Comment: `[{one-off intro object}, [{object},{object},{object}]]` is not valid JSON. If that's not what your JSON is, then don't post it in your question.

Comment: I wasn't aware nobody here understands pseudo-code. My bad. Just delete my question.

Comment: In the part of the JSON that you *are* interested in, do all the objects in that array have the same structure?

Comment: @BrianRogers yes they do

Comment: OK, good; that helps.  I've added an answer to show the basic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) to do the job.

For sake of example, let's assume your JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "blah": "nothing interesting here"
  },
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "foo",
      "desc": "description of foo"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bar",
      "desc": "blurb about bar"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "baz",
      "desc": "buzz about baz"
    }
  ]
]
```

First, define a class to hold the items from the inner array that you're interested in.

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("desc")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now, all you need to do is parse the JSON to a `JArray`, then get the child array from that and use `ToObject()` to convert it to a list of items.

```
JArray ja = JArray.Parse(json);
List<Item> list = ja[1].ToObject<List<Item>>();
```

From there, you can use the list of items as you normally would.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CaFzux

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the second set of objects either via strongly typed casting or dynamically, here is an example of doing it dynamically:

```
dynamic jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);         
dynamic targetJsonObjects = jsonArray[1];
```

Comment: Dynamic should only be used in situations where the structure can't be known at design time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just simple model like this?

```
public class RootObject
{
    public object IntroObject { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string WhatEverPropertyYouNeed{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This structure actually won't work because the outer part of the JSON is an array, not an object.